# Powershell window drops off the bottom of the screen

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I believe this is due to windows scaling, as I have it on 200% (I have a 4k 13" laptop screen).

Are there any settings anywhere I can fiddle with so that it doesn't open with half of it off the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

#### Are there any settings anywhere I can fiddle with?

1. Click on the Powershell Menu button
2. Select "Defaults" or "Properties"

   - Select "Defaults" to change all future Powershell windows
   - Select "Properties" to change the current Powershell window

   [image]
3. Change "Window Size" > "Height as appropriate so that the Window fits on your display.

   [image]